# SQL - Add in a new table join when all left join - Total beginner

Tags: sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I need help with adding in an additional join to my query.

All the tables are currently left outer joined from SO_Header however there is also some data I need from a table called RANGE which only links to the MODEL table.

How can I edit my script to bring in the RANGE table?

I'm using the get data from microsoft query in Excel.

Extract from my script:

```
FROM dbo.SO_HEADER SO_HEADER LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     dbo.WEEK_NUMBERS WEEK_NUMBERS 
     ON SO_HEADER.SOH_Build_Week = WEEK_NUMBERS.WEEK_Week_No AND
        SO_HEADER.SOH_Build_Year = WEEK_NUMBERS.WEEK_Year LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.MODEL MODEL 
     ON SO_HEADER.SOH_Model = MODEL.MODEL_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.RETAILERS RETAILERS 
     ON SO_HEADER.SOH_Retailer = RETAILERS.RET_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.FACTORY_OPTIONS FACTORY_OPTIONS 
     ON SO_HEADER.SOH_Upholstery = FACTORY_OPTIONS.FAC_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.FINANCE_HOUSES FINANCE_HOUSES 
     ON SO_HEADER.SOH_Finance = FINANCE_HOUSES.FIN_Code
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help . . . as would an appropriate database tag.

Comment: What is the key that links the MODEL and RANGE tables? It'll depend on your data model but you'll likely want something like LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RANGE RANGE on RANGE.RANGE_Model = MODEL.MODEL_Code. Basically you just add another join to the child table. But additional details would help to answer this.

Comment: Hi all, Mohammed below was able to solve in the answers questions. @James-geldart your solution suggestion sounded similar :)

Comment: @gordonlinoff I don't know what a database tag is. Unfortunately someone edited my question (I had stated I was a total beginner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a foreign key in your range table with named **RANGE_MODEL_Code** then you can join model and range like this

Also you can change the way you wants to join the table (i-e let join, inner join or outer join) depends on your business requirement

```
FROM dbo.SO_HEADER SO_HEADER LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     dbo.WEEK_NUMBERS WEEK_NUMBERS 
     ON SO_HEADER.SOH_Build_Week = WEEK_NUMBERS.WEEK_Week_No AND
        SO_HEADER.SOH_Build_Year = WEEK_NUMBERS.WEEK_Year LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.MODEL MODEL 
     ON SO_HEADER.SOH_Model = MODEL.MODEL_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.RANGE RANGE
     ON MODEL.MODEL_Code = RANGE.RANGE_MODEL_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.RETAILERS RETAILERS 
     ON SO_HEADER.SOH_Retailer = RETAILERS.RET_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.FACTORY_OPTIONS FACTORY_OPTIONS 
     ON SO_HEADER.SOH_Upholstery = FACTORY_OPTIONS.FAC_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.FINANCE_HOUSES FINANCE_HOUSES 
     ON SO_HEADER.SOH_Finance = FINANCE_HOUSES.FIN_Code
```

Change your table name  and joining keys from both table i-e **RANGE_MODEL_Code** and **MODEL_Code** according to your schema

Comment: Fantastic, this worked perfectly, thank you!